# Parsing images via nokogiri and xpath

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I currently have a piece of code which will grab a product title, description, and price and for that it works great. However, I also need it to get the image URL which is where my dilemma is. I tried using a xpath inside the loop I have at the bottom and it lists out ALL the images that are equal to 220 on EVERY product which I dont want at all. So basically I get something like this....

product 1 Title here

product 1 Description here

product 1  price here

http://www.test.com/product1.jpg

http://www.test.com/product2.jpg

http://www.test.com/product3.jpg

http://www.test.com/product4.jpg

product 2 Title here

product 2 Description here

product 2  price here

http://www.test.com/product1.jpg

http://www.test.com/product2.jpg

http://www.test.com/product3.jpg

http://www.test.com/product4.jpg

Where as I obviously want product 1 to just have http://www.test.com/product1.jpg and product 2 to have http://www.test.com/product2.jpg etc, etc. The images are just in a div tag with no class or ID hence why I didnt just easily put them into a css selector. Im really new to ruby/nokogiri so any help would be great.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


url = "http://thewebsitehere"

data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

products = data.css('.item')



products.each do |product|
    puts product.at_css('.vproduct_list_title').text.strip
    puts product.at_css('.vproduct_list_descr').text.strip
    puts product.at_css('.price-value').text.strip
    puts product.xpath('//img[@width = 220]/@src').map {|a| a.value }

end
```

Comment: We can't help you much if you don't include the HTML you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
puts product.xpath('//img[@width = 220]/@src').map {|a| a.value }
```

to:

```
puts product.xpath('.//img[@width = 220]/@src').map {|a| a.value }
```

The point of the '.' there is to say you want all images that are children of the current node (e.g. so you're not peeking at product 2's images).

Answer (score 0):

`File#basename` will return only the filename:

```
File.basename('http://www.test.com/product4.jpg')
#=> "product4.jpg"
```

So you probably want something like this:

```
puts product.xpath('//img[@width = 220]/@src').map {|a| File.basename(a.value) }
```

Comment: Ah, sorry maybe I didnt explain my situation clearly enough. I actually dont want all the different product images of the entire page on each different product. I want just product 1 to have http://www.test.com/product1.jpg and product 2 to have http://www.test.com/product2.jpg i dont want product 2 to have http://www.test.com/product1.jpg 
http://www.test.com/product2.jpg 
http://www.test.com/product3.jpg 
http://www.test.com/product4.jpg

If that makes more sense. I edited my original post to help clarify. Thanks for that tid bit though, good to know.